# How to visualize HTML component with A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

Please help. I am not able to display HTML content in AR with A-Frame. Please help anyone.

Looking for answer.

Comment: you can try using this html embed component for aframe https://github.com/supereggbert/aframe-htmlembed-component

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an overlay there is a component of the a-scene called webxr which has the property you are looking for: overlayElement.

Example at:

https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/examples/boilerplate/webxr-dom-overlay/index.html

Otherwise there are different components out there which render html as texture and deal with interactions by dispatching them, but none is complete.